# Survey Monkey API Response Missing Date

Tags: php, surveymonkey

I have been working my way through [survey monkey API](https://developer.surveymonkey.com/) using the [PHP wrapper](https://github.com/ewaltman/php-surveymonkey/blob/master/README.md). I get my responses by calling getResponses() without any problem.

However, the array I get back does not contain any information on when was the response received. Is there a way I can get information on when a particular survey response was received? Am I missing something obvious here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The response in 'get_responses' is literally just the answers the user inputted.  The metadata you want is actually held in the respondent details, accessible via [get_respondent_list](https://developer.surveymonkey.com/mashery/get_respondent_list).  There is a date_start that is when they started their response, and date_modified which is the last time they changed it (which when they're done is when they finished it).

Comment: Thanks for that Miles. Have completely missed that optional array.